# What does this -> followed by the namespace before the name of a record in Clojure means?

Tags: clojure

I have seen a following piece of code [here](https://github.com/tombooth/friend-token-redis)

```
  (def token-store
      (redis-store/->RedisTokenStore secret-key 30 {:pool {} :spec {:host "127.0.0.1" :port 6379}}))
```

Can anyone explain what does this mean ?

RedisTokenStore is a record that implements TokenStore protocol and its methods.
but what does this syntax mean, objects can be created with this syntax as well:

```
(RedisTokenStore. secret-key 30 {:pool {} :spec {:host "127.0.0.1" :port 6379}})
```

Then what differently is this symbol -> doing ?
Why is it after a user defined namespace ?

I know as a macro, -> is used to

```
(-> 4 (+ 5)
      (- 6))
```

which translates to (- (+ 4 5) 6) and gives 3. but neither could I google a '->' or type something similar to search what this means.

Answer (score 7):

`RedisTokenStore` is declared with `defrecord` in the namespace.

At the bottom of the [`defrecord` doc](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defrecord):

> Given (defrecord TypeName ...), two factory functions will be defined:
>   ->TypeName, taking positional parameters for the fields, and map->TypeName, taking a map of keywords to field values.

Answer (score 6):

`->RedisTokenStore` is a factory function for record `RedisTokenStore`. Clojure defines it automatically when record is defined.

Here is quote from [official Clojure datatypes docs](http://clojure.org/datatypes):

> when a deftype/defrecord Foo is defined a corresponding function ->Foo is defined that passes its arguments to the constructor (versions 1.3 and later only)

So, `->RedisTokenStore` is a helper function which simply calls `RedisTokenStore.` constructor. The only difference is that you should `import` `RedisTokenStore` class to call its constructor explicitly, while `->RedisTokenStore` is an ordinary function and could be `require`'ed and then used as a part of `redis-store` namespace.

**Update:** As [mattexx poined out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995366/what-does-this-followed-by-the-namespace-before-the-name-of-a-record-in-cloju#19995795), there is also `map->RedisTokenStore` factory function which takes a map as its sole argument.